# Dplyr solution for difference in row values based on two factor levels in separate columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr to calculate the difference between two row values based on factor levels in  large data frame. In practical terms, I want the vote distance between two groups across each party within each country. For the data below, I would like to end up with a data frame with rows indicating the difference between the vote values for each group pair for each party level within each country level. The lag function does not seem to work with my data as the number of factor levels varies by country, meaning each country has a different total number of groups and parties. A small sample of the setup is below.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1:12),
                 country = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b"),
                 group =   c("x","y","z","x","y","z","x","y","z","x","y","z"),
                 party =   c("d","d","d","e","e","e","d","d","d","e","e","e"),
                 vote =    c(.15,.02,.7, .5, .6, .22,.47,.33,.09,.83,.77,.66))
```

This is how I would like the end product to look.

```
df2 <- data.frame(id= c(1:12),
                  country = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","a","a","a","b","b","b"),
                  group1 =  c("x","x","y","x","x","y","x","x","y","x","x","y"),
                  group2 =  c("y","z","z","y","z","z","y","z","z","y","z","z"),
                  party =   c("d","d","d","d","d","d","e","e","e","e","e","e"),
                  dist =  c(.13,-.5,-.68,.14,.38,.24,-.1,.28,.38,.06,.17,.11))
```

I have tried dcast previously and if I fill with the column I want, it doesn't line up and produces NA or 0 where there should be values. The lag function doesn't work in my case because the number of parties and groups are unique for each country and not fixed. Whenever I have tried different intervals for the lag the values are comparing across countries of across parties rather than across groups in some instances.

I have found solutions outside of dplyr but for parsimony in presenting code I am wondering if there is a way in dplyr. Also, the code I have is incredibly long and clunky, and uses six or seven packages just for this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Great first post.  Clear examples and a description of what you tried.

Comment: Thanks! I read a lot of posts and notice that poor wording in the original question leads to a lot of confusion and unclear answers, glad it was clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is to use

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
left_join(df1 %>% select(-id), by = c("country", "party"), suffix = c("1", "2")) %>% 
filter(group1 != group2) %>% 
mutate(dist = vote1 - vote2)
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `combn` to create the difference

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(country,  party) %>% 
    mutate(dist = combn(vote, 2, FUN = function(x) x[1] - x[2]))
```

Comment: Hi Akrun, thank you for the reply. I have nto used the combn function before and when I execute on my actual data I get the dplyr error about column length ("column `dist' must be length X (the group size) or one, not Y") and I believe it is because there are some combinations that may return NA. I cannot seem to resolve the error by adding either drop_na or na.rm within the pipe.

Comment: @shay If your group have less than 2 elements, it could have that issue.  May be for that case you need a `if/else` `mutate(dist = if(n() >1) combn(vote, 2, FUN = function(x) x[1] - x[2]) else NA_real_)`